# Take a screen shot programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, screenshot

Here you can See take screen shot programmatically and display screen shot in Image View and and check weather SD card is in your device or not , To save screen shot in to the SD Card.

Xml(main.xml)

In main.xml Declare all view objects.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_screenshoot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Click Here to Create ScreenShot" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv_showscreenshot"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_screenshoot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Activity(ScreenshotActivity .java)

In this Activity we can see take a screenshot programatically when user click on Button.

```
package com.androidsurya.screenshot;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScreenshotActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn_screenshoot;
    int i = 0;
    ImageView imgv_showscreenshot;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_screenshoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_screenshoot);
        btn_screenshoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View view = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                imgv_showscreenshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv_showscreenshot);
                // set screenshot bitmapdrawable to imageview
                imgv_showscreenshot.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageState())) {
                    // we check if external storage is available, otherwise
                    // display an error message to the user using Toast Message
                    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                            + "/ScreenShots");
                    directory.mkdirs();

                    String filename = "screenshot" + i + ".jpg";
                    File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);

                    while (yourFile.exists()) {
                        i++;
                        filename = "screenshot" + i + ".jpg";
                        yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
                    }

                    if (!yourFile.exists()) {
                        if (directory.canWrite()) {
                            try {
                                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                        yourFile, true);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,
                                        out);
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        ScreenshotActivity.this,
                                        "File exported to /sdcard/ScreenShots/screenshot"
                                                + i + ".jpg",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                i++;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenshotActivity.this,
                            "Sorry SD Card not available in your Device!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

In manifest file to store screenshot in sdcard

is mandatory.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidsurya.screenshot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidsurya.screenshot.ScreenshotActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[After a lot of searching finally this link helps.](http://androidsurya.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-take-screen-shot-programmatically.html)

Comment: can you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/1332870

Answer (score 2):

**Put this on OnCreate**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = "ParentLayoutOFView".getMeasuredHeight();

createImage(height, width, linearLayout, "FileName");
```

**Add this methods**

```
public File createImage(int height, int width, View view, String fileName) {
    Bitmap bitmapCategory = getBitmapFromView(view, height, width);
    return createFile(bitmapCategory, fileName);
}

public File createFile(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {

    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String sdcardPath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
    File reportImageFile = new File(sdcardPath + "/YourFolderName" + fileName + ".jpg");
    try {
        if (reportImageFile.isFile()) {
            reportImageFile.delete();
        }
        if (reportImageFile.createNewFile()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(reportImageFile);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            bytes.close();
            fo.close();

            return reportImageFile;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ReportsActivity.this, "Unable to create Image.Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```