# take a screen shot periodically

Tags: android, screenshot

To take a one-shot, there's a solution(closed). [Take a screen shot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148296/take-a-screen-shot-programmatically)

Is there any sample that takes screen shot periodically on background thread?

Comment: ....and this is the case for closed ecosystems

Comment: Taking a screenshot when an exception happens isn't necessarily a bad idea... But taking one periodically sounds rather shady.

Comment: This is shady please don't help him lol

Comment: :) Ok, guys I'm gonna explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to make a OCR based translation program. But compared to [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two), I want to take an image from screen not from camera. Then my program translate english to korean automatically like tooltip dictionary. That's why I want to take screen shot periodically. Anyway, thank you guys for your quick response and interest though.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you want to repeat the steps mentioned in that solution every X seconds?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay) would give you a good idea on where to begin.

Comment: Thank you @Keno. I'll give it a shot.